# Windows 10 800ms click delay after textarea input

Tags: javascript, windows-10, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

Windows 10 (all browsers) seems to have a 800ms delay between the user has writing input in a `textarea` to user being able to click a button.

To demonstrate, consider this example:

```js
document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  console.time('Delay to click');
});

document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.timeEnd('Delay to click');
});
```

```html
<textarea id="input"></textarea>
<button id="button" type="button">
  Click me
</button>
```

Try to write something in the `textarea` and click the button as fast as possible.

In any browser running in Windows 10 you cannot click the button under 800ms, while in Windows 7/MacOS there seems to not be any limitations.

Is there any way around this delay?

Edit: Tested also on win8.1/IE11 and the delay seems to also appear there.

Comment: i get 188 ms in edge. is yours a touch system?

Comment: Win10 / IE11 and Chrome - I didn't notice any problem.

Comment: no repro for me either. Win10 (1607) with IE11, Edge, or Chrome. I get delays between 102 & 182ms

Comment: A big thank you all for testing. I'll get my hands on some additional pc:s and see if I can narrow this bug down.